# Unlocked bootloader "can't" be checked

Tags: boot, bootloader

I have a Nexus 6p, and I unlocked it's bootloader. There is a message saying that my phone can't be checked for corruption since the bootloader is unlocked. I am a little confused because when I flashed Paranoid Android, the first time it booted into it, the message said that it was corrupt (so far I don't see anything wrong).

How does it know that my phone is corrupt if it can't check for corruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with dm-verity.  Taken from XDA Developers [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/a-look-at-marshmallow-root-verity-complications/):

> The problem (it’s a problem if you like root and modifying devices)
>   stems from something I pointed out a long time back, when it first hit
>   AOSP – the introduction of dm-verity to Android. Verity is a security
>   feature, originally found in ChromeOS, designed to provide assured and
>   trustworthy computing devices, preventing malicious software from
>   modifying a device. Back in Android 4.4, Google announced verity for
>   Android, and then all remained quiet. While there has been some
>   research into using verity, for the most part, things have been quiet.
>   Until now, that is.
>
> With Android 6.0, Google has begun to up their game on device
>   security. One of the fundamental requirements for this is to prevent
>   the software on a device from being modified without a user’s
>   knowledge – while many here at XDA take root for granted, imagine a
>   user’s device being rooted without their knowledge or consent, and
>   root access being used to steal their data. For this reason, Google
>   has started to implement verification of the system partition on some
>   devices.

To answer your question of "How does it know..."...any changes to the system partition at boot (or when accessed) could cause one of three warning/error messages.